# How to recognize deep from loud sounds?

Tags: software, audio, mp3, sound-effects

I found a player at newgrounds.com time ago (cannot find it now, forgot the url, will comment if i find it) that has two pairs of speakers. The upper pair plays loud sounds or screamy sounds but the lower pair plays the deep sounds, like bass or simillar. I talk about mp3 sounds.

My question is how or what should i search in the sound raw data in order to separate deep from loud sounds?

Dont know what tags to add for this type of question, but suggestions would be good :)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding the usual split, which is between low and high pitched sounds. The bass speakers play the low notes and the tweeters play the high ones.

Loud is not opposite to deep. You can have loud low or high notes, or quiet low or high notes.

To answer your identification question - low pitched notes will have only a few waves, whereas high pitched notes have a lot of waves in the same space. It is easy to see when you look at a waveform - are there a lot of peaks (high pitched) or very few (low pitched)

[image]

Image from http://bbamusic.wikispaces.com/Three+Components+of+Sound

Comment: 'It is easy to see when you look at a waveform'
Use FOOBAR2000 and put the visualization to real time spectrum analysis. Then play various records and you'll understand what he's saying.